# IP sharing between guest (ubuntu16.04) and host windows7 in virtual workstation

Tags: networking

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest OS in VMWare workstation with Windows 7 being the host OS. Now I need to share the IP address between the two OS. In other words, I want the IP of the Guest to be the same as the host OS IP address. Any ideas please.

Comment: Normally you don't want two "computers" to have the same IP address on a network. Why do you want/need to? Normally you'd set the guest OS network settings to use `bridged` mode, and it'll pick up its own address on your (sub)net.

Comment: heynnema is correct.  Look at this page on how to configure:  http://www.howtogeek.com/122641/how-to-forward-ports-to-a-virtual-machine-and-use-it-as-a-server/

Comment: Alternatively, if you use NAT mode your VM would have an alternate address, and your host machine would act as a router between your network and the virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks, the reason why i need this is that the IT department in my university gave me a range of IP addresses for windows to use in my lab and go online and open any website. But when I run ubuntu it takes different IP address from the one on Windows and this does not allow me to open the same websites as in windows.

Comment: Charles, does this sort the problem just described??

Comment: Two different computers connected to the same network _cannot_ have the same IP address. That's why it's called an _address_.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in your comment the real goal is to make network requests from the guest OS appear to origin from your host.

This is the exact problem you can solve by telling your virtualization software to use NAT for the virtual interface of your guest. Every packet you send from the guest will be rewritten by the virtualization software with the IP-address of the host as *source-address*.

With VMWare you just edit the settings of the VM and designate the mode NAT for the virtual network interface of the guest (I don't have VMWare at hand right now (and the details are not on topic here anyway)).

From that point on any network device will not be able to determine if a request origins from your host or from the guest. In other words: the uest still has its own IP-address, that will never change - but the packets your guest sends will appear to come from the host's IP-address.

Comment: Thanks alot, Is it something straightforward or need some advance knowledge in the network configuration?

Comment: I am using VM workstation

Comment: I have followed what it has been done in the following demo but did not work. My Host and Guest OS still have two different IP addresses.                    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbgUh16UxKw

Comment: @Ali of course they have different IP-addresses, that will never change - but the packets your guest sends will appear to come from the host's IP-address.

Comment: The issue is that I have a guest (UBUNTU) OS and want to run some GUI softwares that are installed on remote UBUNTU server. So, I have to do the following (setenv DISPLAY  IPaddress of the host) in order for me to load the GUI interface in the guest terminal

Comment: @Ali the usual way to run an X program on a remote host but display it locally (on your guest) is to use `ssh -X user@remotehost`. This will work with NAT.